# Sending a video from Perl to a client over HTTP

Tags: perl, video-streaming, html5-video, audio-streaming

I am currently making a perl script that will convert a file to webm/ogg/mp4 format and then send it back to the user but in embed video. It all works except that I can not send an EOF so the HTML5 video player knows what the end is and so he can correctly use the file (like going to a specific time and even knowing when the file has ended (now it just stops but you can't do anything anymore with the video.

Start-code:

```
elsif ($path =~ /^\/((\w|\d){11})\.webm$/ig) {
    print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n";
    $handler = \&resp_youtubemovie;
    $handler->($cgi,$1);
```

Function to send webm file

```
sub resp_youtubemovie {
    my $cgi = shift;
    my $youtubeID = shift;
    return if !ref $cgi;
    open(movie,"<$youtubeID.webm");
    local($/);
    $movie = <movie>;
    close(movie);
    print "Content-type: movie/webm\n";
    print $movie;
}
```

I've already tried with a while loop and a buffer but that doesn't work either, I've also tried to change the HTTP status code to 206 Partial Content because I wiresharked some other video streaming websites used it but it didn't matter. So anyone an idea how to open a movie file and stream it correctly?

Comment: Try to print 2 blank lines after the video and tell us if it works.

Comment: You mean print "\r\n\r\n"? Also tried that but still didn't work correctly.

Comment: Writing HTTP responses by hand suggests you're writing everything yourself.  This stuff gets very tricky.  Consider using a web framework, [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer) is pretty simple but powerful, that can take care of this and much much more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than doing this by hand, a framework like [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer) can take care of this.  This will save you many, many, many headaches.  It also allows you to take advantage of the [Plack/PSGI](https://metacpan.org/module/PSGI%3a%3aFAQ#So-what-is-this-) superglue which figures out how to talk to web servers for you.

```
use Dancer;

get qr{/(\w{11}\.webm)$}i => sub {
    my($video_file) = splat;

    return send_file(
        $video_file,
        streaming => 1,
    );
}
```

Using [Dancer routes](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer%3a%3aIntroduction#ROUTE-HANDLERS) you should be able to adapt your existing code pretty easily especially if its a big if/elsif matching against various paths.  Dancer does a very good job making simple things simple, it also gives you a huge amount of control over the exact HTTP response if you need it.

A few notes...

- The content-type for [webm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) is `video/webm` which may be the source of your problems.  Dancer should just get it right.  If not you can tell [send_file](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer#send_file) the content type explicitly.
- `(\w|\d){11}` is better written as `\w{11}` since `\w` includes `\d`.

Comment: Already looking into this, I'm just getting stuck at an Error 500 that he is unable to process the query. Still, thanks for the advice on Dancer, seems a bit more powerful than HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI; that I was using.

Comment: Found my error while further reading the documentation, I should have putted the file in a folder named public. Where the server is running isn't the place where files can be handled except if you allow systempaths while sending files.

Odd thing is, in Firefox I can't hear audio while in Chrome I can. It seems the problem lies in Firefox itself but if I find a fix for it I will post it here.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the 206 Partial Content HTTP status and you must also send:

- The `Accept-Range: bytes` header.
- A `Content-Range: 0-2048/123456` header where you send the starting and ending byte index of the content followed by the total byte length of the content. The client will be sending you the byte ranges it wants in the request header. The client may send multiple byte ranges in a single request, in which case you'd also need to send the content with multipart word boundaries.

Finally, to get back to your question, if the client requests a byte range that isn't satisfiable then you send a 416 HTTP status and close the connection.